# Iphone development UIBarButtonItem action

Tags: objective-c, ios

I made in storyboard the layout of my iOS application. Now I want to add events on the buttons. I found on internet that it is easy to drag and drop to add an action.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS-Legacy/chapters/RM_YourFirstApp_iOS/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH7-SW4

But when I do that nothing happens. I do the same as what they say but still I don't see the add outlet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to drag from the storyboard to a .h file.

In the storyboard you have a UIViewController with a button, that UIViewController has a class, you have to drag from the buttom, with the right button, to the .h of the same class the ViewController is.

If you have the assistant editor active, there is a icon like a smoking, click it, set to automatic and then select the .h.